# How to create annotated mask images(ground truth) for image segmentation task from my own dataset

Tags: python, computer-vision, image-segmentation

I am totally new in image segmentation and could really use some help.

So I have now in hand a knee MRI dataset, and also the corresponding mask images produced from another way, when they overlay it looks like this :
[deeper grey areas in the right image are overlayed mask](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DEV6I.png)
Basically a mask image contains black background and ROIs, looks like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoaZu.png)
Now I want to convert the mask images into ground truth images for when I train a model for image segmentation using this dataset.

I tried using them directly in a test run, dice coefficient is highly unusual, and prediction shows completely nothing at all. I trolled through materials I can find online, but nothing works. The LabelBox tool seems right, but somehow I cannot correctly import it at all.

Is there a way (preferably in Python instead of external tools) to convert directly my mask images into whichever format required to form a proper training set for image segmentation task?